# Breaking up a sequence of id numbers using tokenize

Tags: xml, xquery, tokenize

I have an XML file that looks like this:

```
<cosmetics>
<cosmetic id="0" itemIDs="1879053261,1879053932,1879054863"/>
<cosmetic id="1" itemIDs="1879176339"/>
<cosmetic id="2" itemIDs="1879115954"/>
<cosmetic id="3" itemIDs="1879051065,1879057689"/>
</cosmetics>
```

What I want is a file that looks like this:

```
<cosmetics>
<cosmetic id="0">
    <item id="1879053261"/>
    <item id="1879053932"/>
    <item id="1879054863"/>
</cosmetic>
<cosmetic id="1">
    <item id="1879176339"/>
</cosmetic>
etc
```

I feel like I am close to a solution in XQuery using the tokenize function, something like this:

```
for $newcosmetic in doc("cosmetics.xml")/cosmetics/cosmetic/
return <cosmetic id="{$newcosmetic/@id}">
    for $itemid in $newcosmetic/tokenize(@itemIDs,",") 
    return <itemid id="{$itemid}"/>
</cosmetic>
```

But I'm definitely screwing it up somehow. That code above probably only demonstrates how new I am to XQuery. I've searched all through stack overflow and elsewhere, and I am having trouble finding an example that I can directly link to my own problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you getting an error? Incorrect output?

Comment: Right now I'm getting an error telling me there is "unexpected token: id [at line 3, column 18]". I have no idea what is causing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you just need to:

- remove the trailing `/` from `doc("cosmetics.xml")/cosmetics/cosmetic/`
- wrap the inner for in `{}`

Example:

```
for $newcosmetic in doc("cosmetics.xml")/cosmetics/cosmetic
return <cosmetic id="{$newcosmetic/@id}">{
    for $itemid in $newcosmetic/tokenize(@itemIDs,",") 
    return <itemid id="{$itemid}"/>
}</cosmetic>
```

And if you want to output `cosmetics`, it's just wrapping everything in `<cosmetics>{}</cosmetics>`:

```
<cosmetics>{
for $newcosmetic in doc("cosmetics.xml")/cosmetics/cosmetic
return <cosmetic id="{$newcosmetic/@id}">{
    for $itemid in $newcosmetic/tokenize(@itemIDs,",") 
    return <itemid id="{$itemid}"/>
}</cosmetic>
}</cosmetics>
```

Also something to note since you're new, instead of doing:

```
id="{$newcosmetic/@id}"
```

you can just include `$newcosmetic/@id` in the inner `{}` (separated by a comma)...

```
<cosmetics>{
for $newcosmetic in doc("cosmetics.xml")/cosmetics/cosmetic
return <cosmetic>{$newcosmetic/@id,
    for $itemid in $newcosmetic/tokenize(@itemIDs,",") 
    return <itemid id="{$itemid}"/>
}</cosmetic>
}</cosmetics>
```

Last note...

The second arg of `tokenize()` is a regular expression, so if it's possible to have spaces on either side of the comma, consider something like:

```
$newcosmetic/tokenize(@itemIDs,"\s*,\s*")
```

The other option is to normalize the space on output:

```
<itemid id="{normalize-space($itemid)}"/>
```

Comment: WHOA! I was closer than I thought, that worked like a charm, thanks so much!

Comment: @HansMessersmith - Yes you were super close! I'm glad my answer helped.

Comment: @HansMessersmith - Added one last note, just in case there's the possibility of spaces on either side of your comma separator.